# Scripteable partitions using parted

Tags: gparted, parted

This are my original partition tables of my device

```
Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name        Flags
19      210MB   4370MB  4161MB  ext4         SYSTEM
20      4370MB  4633MB  262MB   ext4         CACHE
21      4633MB  4638MB  5243MB  ext4         HIDDEN
```

I tried to shrink size from system and cache partition and deleted hidden to make Vendor partitions. I followed parted commands to do

```
parted /dev/block/mmcblk0 
rm 19
rm 20
rm 21
mkpart SYSTEM ext4 210MiB 4000MiB 
mkpart CACHE ext4 4000MiB 4200MiB
mkpart VENDOR ext4 4200MiB 4638MiB
name 19 SYSTEM 
name 20 CACHE
name 21 VENDOR
```

I am trying to make this scriptable which can be flashed through recovery

```
#!/bin/bash
echo Applying resize operation
cd /sbin/
chmod u+x /parted
parted --script /dev/block/mmcblk0 \
    rm 19 \
    rm 20 \
    rm 21 \
    mkpart SYSTEM ext2 210MiB 4000MiB \
    mkpart CACHE ext2 4000MiB 4200MiB \
    mkpart VENDOR ext2 4200MiB 4638MiB \
    name 19 SYSTEM \
    name 20 CACHE \
    name 21 VENDOR \
```

but when I flashed I get an error in log

```
minzip: Extracted file "/sbin/parted"
minzip: Extracted file "/sbin/script.sh"
about to run program [/sbin/script.sh] with 1 args
run_program: execv failed: No such file or directory
run_program: child exited with status 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Does `/bin/bash` exist in your recovery environment? The fact that the messages you're seeing refer to `minzip` and `run_program` indicate that the recovery environment might be quite strictly stripped-down: it might have a different, more compact shell like `dash` instead of `bash`.

It looks like your actual script is also adding `parted` to the system:

```
minzip: Extracted file "/sbin/parted"
```

But did you ensure that all the libraries required by `parted` are also present? You can use the `ldd` command to view the list of libraries an executable (or another library) depends on. For example, here's the list of dependencies from an x86_64 version of `parted`. Your actual list will probably be different, depending on options chosen when compiling `parted`, your system architecture and the pathname conventions of the Linux distribution you're using.

```
$ ldd /sbin/parted 
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff609a000)
    libparted.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libparted.so.2 (0x00007f9d17be2000)
    libreadline.so.7 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7 (0x00007f9d17995000)
    libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007f9d1776b000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9d173cc000)
    libuuid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libuuid.so.1 (0x00007f9d171c7000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f9d16fc3000)
    libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdevmapper.so.1.02.1 (0x00007f9d16d6f000)
    libblkid.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libblkid.so.1 (0x00007f9d16b29000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f9d18048000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0x00007f9d16921000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007f9d166f9000)
    libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1 (0x00007f9d1822e000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f9d164dc000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f9d161d8000)
    libpcre.so.3 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3 (0x00007f9d15f65000)
```

Here, `linux-vdso.so.1` is a virtual shared object provided by the kernel itself. But all the rest are libraries that must be present or else `parted` cannot be successfully loaded for execution.

If your environment did not already have `parted` installed, it's fairly likely it also did not have `libparted.so.*` installed. Missing that library would have caused the failure of the `parted` command.

The error message

```
run_program: execv failed: No such file or directory
```

is probably trying to tell you that either the command file itself, *or one of the libraries it depends on*, was not available. A proper shell might have displayed a more detailed error message, but here the message seems to be coming from `run_program`, which I suppose is the thing that is trying to start your script in the first place.